# INSTALL PLUGIN 'rpl_semi_sync_master' SONAME 'semisync_master.so' not working

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.5, windows

I'm trying to install semi synchronous replication in my mysql 5.5 and trying to execute the below command:

```
INSTALL PLUGIN 'rpl_semi_sync_master' SONAME 'semisync_master.so'
```

but this command is throwing the below error:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
''rpl_semi_sync_master' SONAME 'semisync_master.so'' at line 1
```

Please help regarding this. We are using Win7 Professional SP1 32-bit OS.

Thank You

Comment: .so is a Unix shared library. You're using Windows?

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem with your attempt is that you put quotes around the plugin name, along with the fact that you used a `.so` suffix to the library name.

Step-by-step:

Check that your MySQL install is `dynamic_loading` capable:

```
mysql> show variables like '%dynamic%';
+----------------------+-------+
| Variable_name        | Value |
+----------------------+-------+
| have_dynamic_loading | YES   |
+----------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Check that your plugin directory is set correctly:

```
mysql> show variables like '%plugin%';
+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                                               |
+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| plugin_dir    | C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib\plugin\ |
+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Then verify the `.dll` exists in that location:

[image: explorer window, showing the .DLL]

The plugin install should then work OK:

```
mysql> INSTALL PLUGIN rpl_semi_sync_master SONAME 'semisync_master.dll';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: I dread MySQL for Windows. +1 for your tolerance.